# does the supremum of a complement exist

Tags: real-analysis

We have that A has a supremum $\sup (A)$. Do $\sup \overline{A}$ and $\inf \overline{A}$ exist?

If both $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ exist, do $\sup \overline{A}$ and $\inf \overline{A}$ still exist?

Comment: Can you specify what set $A$ lies in? Are you requiring that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, or something else? Also, what have you tried and what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Think of $A$ as an interval.

Comment: A is a subset of R

Answer (score 0):

Always try something. Try the easiest thing you can. For instance, take $A=[0,1]$. It has both a maximum and minimum, thus both a supremum and infimum. Its complement is not bounded (not above nor below) and thus has no supremum nor an infimum.

The only way to solve a problem is to interact with it. If you try to solve it the same way you would try to win a staring contest and just wait for the solution to fall from the sky, you're in for a long waiting period.

Comment: So if A was bounded above but not below, does that mean that the complement was not bounded above but is bounded below?